# Sparse Principal Components Analysis: Any practical examples with fixed rank correlation matrix?

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, linear-algebra

Consider the problem of sparse principal component analysis:
$$\max_{||{\bf x}||_0=k,||{\bf x}||_2=1} {\bf x}^T{\bf A}{\bf x}$$
where a $k$-sparse $n$-dim. unit vector that "maximizes variance" is to be found.
I was wondering if there were any practical (i.e. not artificial :)) examples where the correlation matrix ${\bf A}$ has fixed and low rank, or it is a low rank update, i.e. ${\bf A} = c{\bf I}+{\bf C}{\bf C}^T$, where $c$ is a constant and ${\bf C}$ has low and fixed rank independent of $n$.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Most examples of principal component analysis are of the type you describe (since people usually want to know the (eg) top three principal components). Look at SVDPACK or PROPACK.

**Edit** It is true that I missed the requirement that the vector itself be sparse. In that case, you might want to look at [OptSpace.](http://www.stanford.edu/~swoh/software.html)

Comment: ...but in general, the *actual* principal vectors won't be sparse, so Anadim's problem doesn't seem reduce to standard principal component analysis.

Comment: I was trying to find practical models where the covariance is extremely (i.e. 2 or 3) low rank plus a scaled identity. This can be interpreted as some small number of hidden variables generating a tall random vector plus i.i.d. noise. Now why would we care for sparse vectors that maximize variance? Because they are cheaper to store and much easier to interpret. There is a whole literature on that kind of problems referred to as the sparse principal component analysis.